# Control-f doesn't work on sublime text on ubuntu inside a mac vmware fusion

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, sublimetext3

When you try to use control-f on sublime text that is on ubuntu that is running inside a vm on a mac, find next instead of find is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the default ubuntu key mapping for vmware fusion maps command-f to F3. All you have to do is go to Virtual Machine > Settings > Keyboard and Mouse > Ubuntu Profile > Key Mappings, and uncheck the field that maps ctrl f to f3. Not sure why the guys at vmware thought this would be a good idea. It's non-obvious behaviour because I was testing it in firefox inside ubuntu and it worked (f3 is also "find" alongside ctrl-f) so I thought it was a sublime problem. Hopefully this will help someone.